# Import data into SQL Server with differences in some column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an Excel file that I imported into a table (with customerID, Customer name, accountID, Address, and accountmanagerID) in my SQL Server database.
Now I want to split the data into different tables, for customers, accounts, address, and managers.

The issue is that some customers have more then 5 accounts with different managers others with 2 different account with the same manager.

If I use the stored procedure shown here, I can only store one customer with one account.

But what I want to do is to store one customer with all the different accounts related to him.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Import_Client]
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE Customers
    TRUNCATE TABLE Addresses
    TRUNCATE TABLE Accounts
    TRUNCATE TABLE Managers

    DECLARE NewClient CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
    FOR 
       SELECT
           Distinct(CustomerName), --CustomerName
           AccountID , --AccountNo
           Address,
           ManagerName -- manager
       FROM 
           OldDetails 

    DECLARE @CustomerName VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @Contact VARCHAR(300) 
    DECLARE @AccountNo VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @Address1 VARCHAR(300) 
    DECLARE @CustomerID INT

    OPEN NewClient

    FETCH FROM NewClient INTO @CustomerName, @Manager, @AccountNo, @Address1

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        --- 1 Insert Customer
        INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName)
        VALUES (@CustomerName)

        ---Set the CustomerID to continue with stage 2
        SET @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        --- 2 Insert CustomerAddresses
        INSERT INTO Address (CustomerID,  Address1)
        VALUES (@CustomerID, @Address1) 

        ---3 Insert Managers
        INSERT INTO Managers (CustomerID, Name)
        VALUES (@CustomerID, @Contact)

        ---4 Insert Account
        INSERT INTO Accounts(CustomerID, AccountNo, Manager)
        VALUES (@CustomerID, @AccountNo, @manager)

        FETCH NEXT FROM NewClient INTO @CustomerName, @Manager, @AccountNo, @Address1
    END

    CLOSE NewClient
    DEALLOCATE NewClient
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: It appears your database **design** is broken - it's not the fault of the stored procedure if you can't store your data properly...

Comment: Hey @marc_s, what about pointing him in the right direction then?

Comment: I think there's support to store multiple accounts / managers from what I can see. It might be the stored procedure needs to be changed when inserting the new customer to check if it already exists ?

Comment: In order to help you fix the design flaws, we need to know the current table structures - what tables do you have? What columns (including their datatypes!) do these tables have? What kind of foreign keys are in place?

Comment: thanks for you input and advices, I am kinda new on SQL server but i will apply your advices, Basically the table that i am focusing on are customers, Accounts, addresses and Managers but the data come from a table that i jst created when i was coping importing the data from excel. all the PK are int & auto generated and Fk are int in those 4 tables and other columns are Varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to change the step 1 in your procedure to check if the customer already exists, and if it does, use it instead of inserting a new row for it. You can use the code block below instead of your INSERT statement:

```
-- SET THE @CustomerID
SET     @CustomerID = NULL

SELECT  @CustomerID = ID
FROM    Customers
WHERE   CustomerName = @CustomerName

IF @CustomerID IS NULL
BEGIN
    --- 1 Insert Customer
    INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName)
    VALUES (@CustomerName)

    ---Set the CustomerID to continue with stage 2
    SET @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

This way, you can save only 1 customer record, and multiple rows for managers / accounts if needed.

Hope it makes sense.

**EDIT**
By the way, a small observation, you dont need to specify FAST_FORWARD and READ_ONLY together because FAST_FORWARD implies READ_ONLY and FORWARD_ONLY, so FAST_FORWARD will do it.

Comment: Thanks Horia, I will try it now and let you know

Comment: Good to hear that, dont forget to mark as answer for your question. Thanks.